# pandas drop values in a columns based other columns

Tags: python, pandas, delete-row

Is there a way to drop a single entry in a df?

```
df1:
ID  Count1  Value1  Count2  Value2
111 5   10  5   25
112 4   15  6   25
113 6   7   4   10
114 3   8   2   1
115 7   1   8   10
```

I want to drop any Value1 if Count1 < 5 and drop any Value2 if Count2 < 5.  The result would be like this:

```
ID  Count1  Value1  Count2  Value2
111 5   10  5   25
112 NA  NA  6   25
113 6   7   4   NA
114 NA  NA  NA  NA
115 7   1   8   10
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using loc

```
df.loc[df['Count1'] < 5, ['Count1','Value1']] = np.nan
df.loc[df['Count2'] < 5, ['Count2','Value2']] = np.nan

    ID  Count1  Value1  Count2  Value2
0   111 5.0     10.0    5.0     25.0
1   112 NaN     NaN     6.0     25.0
2   113 6.0     7.0     NaN     NaN
3   114 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
4   115 7.0     1.0     8.0     10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df[['Count1','Value1']] = df[['Count1','Value1']].mask(df.Count1 < 5)
df[['Count2','Value2']] = df[['Count2','Value2']].mask(df.Count2 < 5)

print (df)
    ID  Count1  Value1  Count2  Value2
0  111     5.0    10.0     5.0    25.0
1  112     NaN     NaN     6.0    25.0
2  113     6.0     7.0     NaN     NaN
3  114     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
4  115     7.0     1.0     8.0    10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

df1= df1[df1['Count1'] < 5 & df1['Count2'] < 5]